# Accessing Public Variant Array from Module

Tags: arrays, vba, module, vb6, public

Say I have two files Form1.frm and Module1.bas in a Visual Basic 6 project.

Form1.frm:

```
Public myArray As Variant

Private Sub Form_Load()
  ReDim myArray(2)
  Call PopulateArrays
End Sub
```

Module1.bas:

```
Public Sub PopulateArrays()
Form1.myArray(0) = Array(1, 2, 3)
Form1.myArray(1) = Array(4, 5, 6)
Form1.myArray(2) = Array(7, 8, 9)
End Sub
```

The issues is that once the code runs, 'myArray' remains empty. 
If I put the PopulateArrays Sub within the main Form1.frm the arrays do populate.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the code posted only the variation that does not work?

Comment: usually there is a problem when you have a public array in a form, '... arrays, ... not allowed as public members of object modules'. I'm surprised you haven't come across it.
Since that should be a problem, perhaps try moving the array to the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain things you can't declare in an object module (userforms are just special object modules) and one of them is arrays. If you had declared

```
Public myArray() As Variant
```

Then you would have got a compile error that said as much and would have known. But since you declared as Variant, the compiler didn't complain, but the assignment just doesn't work.

One option is to make the Variant array private and use property statements (this is VBA, but should be the same for VB6). In the userform

```
Private mmyArray() As Variant

Public Property Get myArray() As Variant
    myArray = mmyArray
End Property

Public Property Let myArray(lmyArray As Variant)
    mmyArray = lmyArray
End Property


Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    MsgBox Join(Me.myArray(0), "_")

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ReDim mmyArray(2)
    PopulateArrays

End Sub
```

And in a standard module

```
Public Sub PopulateArrays()

    Dim ar(0 To 2) As Variant

    ar(0) = Array(1, 2, 3)

    UserForm1.myArray = ar

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you've used a workaround to let your Form1 hold a public array. However, I think a better solution would be: (A) move the array to the module and make it public (B) create [accessor/mutator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882691/creating-vb-array-that-is-public-within-class-module) for it.

If you aren't keeping multiple instances of the form at the same time, then (A) is the simplest solution.

Here is the code I tested for (A),
Form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call PopulateArrays
    Call displayArray
End Sub

Private Sub displayArray()
    Dim v1 As Variant
    Dim s As String

    For Each v1 In myArray
        s = s + Join(v1, ", ") + vbNewLine
    Next v1
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Dim form1 As UserForm1
Public myArray As Variant

Public Sub start()
    Set form1 = New UserForm1
End Sub

Public Sub PopulateArrays()
    ReDim myArray(2)
    myArray(0) = Array(1, 2, 3)
    myArray(1) = Array(4, 5, 6)
    myArray(2) = Array(7, 8, 9)
End Sub
```