# Get around 64k limit in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I need to update this old code in VB and I have run into a problem. I have added fields to this structure and now when I try to compile I get this error:

[image]

From reading online most people suggest to break up the structure. The issue with that is I am receiving the data in this format from the firmware. So I would like to keep it as is, but find a way to get around this.

My structure looks like this:

```
Public Type DATA_V2_T
    1_offsets(6399) As Single
    2_offsets(6399) As Single
    init_d_offsets(1199) As Single
    init_a_offsets(1199) As Single
    e_offsets(999)   As Single
    d_offsets(749) As Single
    a_offsets(1199) As Single
    final_e_offsets(6399) As Single
End Type
```

The fields that I have now added are 1_offsets and 2_offsets which cause the error to occur. It seems like this code was getting around this somewhat because the following is defined as a global:

```
Global data_v2 AS DATA_V2_T
```

Can I do something like this for the structure as well?

Edit: I have tried to make a class. I Was able to define my variables like this:

```
    Private 1_offsets(6399) As Single
    Private 2_offsets(6399) As Single
    Private init_d_offsets(1199) As Single
    Private init_a_offsets(1199) As Single
    Private e_offsets(999)   As Single
    Private d_offsets(749) As Single
    Private a_offsets(1199) As Single
    Private final_e_offsets(6399) As Single
```

I created property get methods to access these private variables like so:

```
Property Get p1_offsets() As Single()
    p1_offsets = 1_offsets
End Property
```

The compiler doesn't seem to be complaining about this. But I also need to be able to set the values of the arrays and I am running into trouble with property set. How can I do this?

Comment: Rather than a Type, could you instead use a Class with the same structure?

Comment: Are you passing this to an external library via declare function? If so you could create a byte array of the correct ( > 64kb) size to create a contiguous region of memory & pass that instead of the UDT. The external function will populate it & when it returns you can CopyMemory() from the buffer into 2 smaller UDTs - say one with the 2 offset fields and the other with the remaining fields.

Comment: Can you show how the data is being read into the struct?

Comment: @BrianMStafford I am attempting to do so. I've been able to set them as private and use Property Get to retrieve them. But I also need to modify them and am having trouble with property set.

Comment: @Dan You could always update your question with what you have tried, and we could provide help with any issues you are having with the class.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Okay I did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to define your data as `Variant`.  Here's an example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim one_offsets(6399) As Single
   one_offsets(0) = 33
   one_offsets(1) = 44

   Dim d As Data
   Set d = New Data
   d.one_offsets = one_offsets
End Sub
```

and then in your Data class:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_1_offsets As Variant
Private m_2_offsets As Variant
Private m_init_d_offsets As Variant
Private m_init_a_offsets As Variant
Private m_e_offsets As Variant
Private m_d_offsets As Variant
Private m_a_offsets As Variant
Private m_final_e_offsets As Variant

Public Property Get one_offsets() As Variant
   one_offsets = m_1_offsets
End Property

Public Property Let one_offsets(ByVal Value As Variant)
   m_1_offsets = Value
End Property
```

If you then inspect `m_1_offsets` in the Watch window, you will see it is defined as `Variant/Single(0 to 6399)`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested that this works yet, but I've made a class like this:

```
Public 1_offsets As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim 1_offsets(0 To 6399)
End Sub
```

And everything compiled

Got this from here: [Creating VB array that is public, within class module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882691/creating-vb-array-that-is-public-within-class-module)

Comment: Just tested the snippet and this won't compile as is. The compiler complains that `1_offsets` is not an identifier (obviously) because in *most* languages (VB6 included) identitifiers start with a *letter* and cannot *start* with a digit although digits after first letter are fine.

Comment: @wqw i just renamed my values to make the problem simpler when I posted it.